# Remap ? in NERDTree

Tags: vim, nerdtree, remap

Since ? is usually used to search strings upwards I'd love to be able to use this also in NERDTree.

Using ? in NERDTree always brings me to help, but I just want to search upwards and don't want to cycle through the whole tree with / (downwards search)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NERD_Tree provides a way to change its default mappings via global config variables. Just put the following into your `~/.vimrc` to change it to <kbd>F1</kbd>:

```
:let g:NERDTreeMapHelp = '<F1>'
```

Comment: this sometimes doesn't work. it shows e.g. on nerdtree window, Press <F1> for help. but if you press F1, help didn't show.

Comment: Really? I'm using the latest plugin version from the author's GitHub repo.

Comment: @IngoKarkat here is 4.2.0, tried both in terminal and gvim... anyway, it should work.

Answer (score 4):

NERD_Tree sets a custom filetype when it creates its window. You can hook into that with an `:autocmd` that removes the buffer-local mapping for `?`. Unfortunately, it apparently sets the filetype *before* setting up it's mappings, but something like this should work (except for directly after opening the tree for the first time):

Put the following into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
:autocmd FileType nerdtree autocmd WinEnter,CursorHold <buffer> silent! nunmap <buffer> ?
```

---

Edit: I've just submitted a [patch](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/pull/234) to the author that would enable this shorter and better hook (though the config variable would still be preferred for this particular use case):

```
:autocmd FileType nerdtree silent! nunmap <buffer> ?
```